# What is the "kube-system" namespace for?

Tags: openshift, kubernetes, openshift-origin

In a default openshift install, there is an unused project titled `kube-system`. It seems like `openshift-infra` is for things like metrics, `default` is for the router and registry, and `openshift` is for global templates.

What is the `kube-system` project used for though? I can't find any docs on it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`kube-system` is the namespace for objects created by the Kubernetes system.

Typically, this would contain pods like `kube-dns`, `kube-proxy`, `kubernetes-dashboard` and stuff like fluentd, heapster, ingresses and so on.

Comment: So these types of pods would be deployed by the cluster admin post install?

Comment: I believe they are usually being deployed when creating the kube cluster by the kube master. These pods are controlled by deployments, replica 
 sets or daemon sets (fluentd)
`kubectl get deploy --namespace=kube-system`, `kubectl get rs --namespace=kube-system` or `kubectl get ds --namespace=kube-system`

Answer (score 16):

`kube-system` contains service accounts which are used to run the kubernetes controllers.  These service accounts are granted significant permissions (create pods anywhere, for instance).  Since openshift builds on top of kube, we inherit the structure.

You should avoid putting anything "personal" in that namespace since kube considers it to be "owned" by kube and the permissions for the SAs inside are quite high.